# CSS and PHP: Make a clickable button influence a number

Tags: button, numbers, clickable

i've a clickable heart icon and i've a number at his right. I want the number to change everytime i click the heart. Do you know how can i achieve that? i'm messing around with PHP and CSS. The codes are these ones:

```
<span class="like-post" title="Like">
            <span class="icon"> </span>
            <span class="number"> 0 </span>
        </span>
```

and the style.css

```
.like-post {
font-size: 11px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #555;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
width: 28px;
height: 15px;
margin-left:3px;
}

.icon  {
display: block;
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
position:relative;
top: 3px;
left:1px;
background: url('images/heart15.png');
}

.number  {
display: BLOCK;
float: right;
position: relative;
top: -14px;
 }
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write some jQuery to send an AJAX request to your PHP script on a `.click()` event and use `.text()` to change the number with the result from AJAX.

Comment: urgh, thank you for the answer but i don't know how to begins with jquery and AJAX...can you guide me a little bit ? i don't think that it's a really long way, it's just a heart and a number..thanks!

Comment: i found a wp plugin who makes this. it's called "i recommend this" it's simple and cool. thanks anyway.